# How to convert object data to dropdown options?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created two dropdowns and I am getting the back-end data. Here, I wat to display the list of websites and stores as dropdown.

```
[
  {
    store: [],
    website: "storeuiteam",
  },
  {
    store: ["MSP_BASE"],
    website: "base",
  },
]
```

I want option like:

```
const tableDropdownOptions = [
  { value: "website1", label: "website1" },
  { value: "website2", label: "website2" },
];
```

Comment: const tableDropdownOptions =  [{value: "website1", label: "website1"},{value: "website2", label: "website2"}]

Comment: Can you please show us what you have done so far and we will try to lead you on a right track?

Comment: let webData=[
            {
                "store": [],
                "website": "storeuiteam"
            },
            {
                "store": [
                    "MSP_BASE"
                ],
                "website": "base"
            }
        ]
        let response = [];
        webData.map((value, index)=>{
                
       response.push({
                        "key": value.website,
                        "value": value.website,
                        
                    })
                    
                
            });

Comment: you do not need `arr.push()` inside `arr.map(fn)`, `arr.map()` will return a new array.  `const res = [1, 2, 3].map(v => v * 2); // res [2, 4, 6]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you need? This pretty much is the same as your comment without the count.

```js
const response = [{
  "store": [],
  "website": "storeuiteam"
}, {
  "store": ["MSP_BASE"],
  "website": "base"
}]

const options = response.map(item => ({ key: item.website, value: item.website }));

console.log(options)
```

**EDIT**

Here is a snippet that returns exactly the expected output

```js
const response = [{
  "store": [],
  "website": "storeuiteam"
}, {
  "store": ["MSP_BASE"],
  "website": "base"
}]

const options = response.map((_, index) => ({ key: `website${index + 1}`, value: `website${index + 1}` }));

console.log(options)
```

Comment: 0: {key: "storeuiteam", value: "storeuiteam"}
1: {key: "base", value: "base"}
this is your output

Comment: const tableDropdownOptions = [{value: "website1", label: "website1"},{value: "website2", label: "website2"}]

Comment: So you just want the string ```website``` with the number?

Comment: @LavGupta, I edited the answer to include the output you provided